# SwiftUI @EnvironmentObejct can't seem update values

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-environment

I'm trying to use @EnvironmentObject to update the Boolean values in the ViewModel. So when I navigate back to the original screen I want the boolean values to have change and therefore changing the text. Tried this with ObservedObject too. This is not working or can not find a way for ContentView to redraw itself upon change.

```
import SwiftUI

class Global: ObservableObject {

    @Published var change = [false, false]

}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NewView().environmentObject(Global())
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NewView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var env: Global

    var body: some View {

        Text(env.change[1] ? "WORKS" : "DOESNT WORK")
        NavigationLink(destination: ChangeThis().environmentObject(Global())) {
            Text("Push Me to Change")
        }
    }
}

struct ChangeThis: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var env: Global

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            env.change[0] = true
            env.change[1] = true
        }) {
            Text(" Want this to Changes the Boolean values in Global and update NewView with those values after clicking back")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same instance of the `Global` EnvironmentObject in all your views:

```
struct NewView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var env: Global
    ...
    // pass the already-existing instance, don't create a new one
    NavigationLink(destination: ChangeThis().environmentObject(env) 
    ...
}
```